# EF error with two SQL Azure databases - a partial method may not have multiple defining declarations

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database

Adding two different SQL Azure databases to my solution - DB1.edmx and DB2.edmx. They have different connection strings and object contexts initialized. The databases do not have any common table names. However,  during compilation it returns an error 
"a partial method may not have multiple defining declarations entity framework". This is due to some  tables (federation_distribution_history, federation_member_distribution_history etc) that are common across SQL Azure databases.

What is the right approach to solving this issue?

Comment: Put the contexts in different namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by GertArnold, please use two different namespaces. Classes in different namespaces are considered different even if the names are same. You can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z2kcy19k(v=vs.100).aspx for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.